# Why does the SSIS Script Task fail to evaluate an expression?

Tags: c#, sql-server, ssis, etl, business-intelligence

#### SSIS Script Task Error

I have a table with directories and file names then which i want to use as a connection string to/from a text file.

I use a foreach loop to get the values from the table assigned to variables, than i have an expression variable which is a combination from the source Dir + source filename, and since there is no other way to check if a file exists in SSIS only with a script task, i did so

```
public void chkIfExist()
{
    if (File.Exists(Dts.Variables["User::srcFull"].Value.ToString()))
    {
        Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;    
    }
    else
    {
        Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Failure;
    }
}
```

note: `User::srcFull` is an expression veriable `@[User::srcPath] +  @[User::srcFile]`

it kept on crashing on me, so i placed a watch in the script at runtime for `Dts.Variables["User::srcFull"].Value.ToString()` and i get and function evaluation timed out.

I tried to figure out whats going on and i came on the conclution that since the values are coming from a rawset that's why the script component cannot evaluate it...

Why does the expression fail to evaluate correctly within the Script Task? Does anyone how to resolve this issue?

Comment: I actually use a data flow task to get the data into a rowset destination, and yes i'm using a Foreach ADO enumerator to get the read the variables, so i get the path in the path variable and the filename in the file variable. so i need to verify if the file exists in a script component so i got another variable which is a combo of the path and the file, there is where i get a evaluation timeout

Comment: siva,
my issue is not that the script doesn't find the file, it's that it cannot evaluate the `Dts.Variables["User::srcFull"].Value.ToString()`

Comment: in the expression builder i get no errors, it's actually now a `ReadWriteVariables` is that a difference?

Comment: I also tried to assign a constant expression like 1+1 to the `User::srcFull` variable and it worked, the only time when it doesn't work is when it comes from the table...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Possible option:

You could use *`Execute SQL Task`* to fetch the record set instead of using a *`Data Flow Task`*.

#### SSIS 2012 package illustrating the example:

Let us assume that you have a table named `dbo.FileNames` in your data database with the some sample rows.

#### Create and populate table script:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.FileNames(
    srcPath nvarchar(255) NULL,
    srcName nvarchar(60) NULL
);

GO

INSERT INTO dbo.FileNames (srcPath, srcName) VALUES
        ('C:\temp', 'File_1.txt')
    ,   ('C:\temp', 'File_2.txt')
    ,   ('C:\temp', 'File_3.txt')
    ;
GO
```

Configure the *Control Flow* tab as shown below. Place an *`Execute SQL Task`* to read the table data and store it in an object data type. Place a `Foreach Loop Container` after the Execute SQL Task and a *`Script Task`* within the *Foreach Loop Container*

[image: Control Flow tab]

Create the following variables. It is advisable to use the expression `@[User::srcPath] + "\\" + @[User::srcFile]` on the variable *`srcFull`* so that if the path is missing a trailing backslash, it will be added accordingly in between the path and file name.

```
Variable name  Scope         Data type  Expression
-------------- ------------- ---------- -----------
FileNames      SO_15072939   Object
srcFile        SO_15072939   String
srcFull        SO_15072939   String     @[User::srcPath] + "\\" + @[User::srcFile]
srcPath        SO_15072939   String
```

[image: Variables]

Configure the *Execute SQL Task* to run the below query against the connection manager to read the file path and name information.

```
SELECT srcPath, srcName FROM dbo.FileNames
```

[image: Execute SQL Task - General]

The result set returned by the query should be stored into the variable *`FileNames`* of data type *`Object`*.

[image: Execute SQL Task - Result Set]

Configure the *`Foreach Loop Container`* to read the variable *FileNames* using *`Foreach ADO Enumerator`*.

[image: Foreach Loop Container - Collection]

Configure the two package variables to store the column values as the result set is being looped through.

[image: Foreach Loop Container - Variable Mappings]

Configure the *Script Task Editor* to read the variable **`srcFull`**

[image: Script Task Editor]

Add the below code to the Script Task.

#### Script task code in C# for SSIS 2008 and above:

```
#region Namespaces
using System;
using System.Data;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
#endregion

namespace ST_f1d7b6ab42e24ad5b5531684ecdcae87
{
    [Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.SSISScriptTaskEntryPointAttribute]
    public partial class ScriptMain : Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.VSTARTScriptObjectModelBase
    {
        public void Main()
        {
            string filePath = Dts.Variables["User::srcFull"].Value.ToString();

            MessageBox.Show(filePath);

            Dts.TaskResult = File.Exists(filePath)
                                ? (int)ScriptResults.Success
                                : (int)ScriptResults.Failure;
        }

        #region ScriptResults declaration
        enum ScriptResults
        {
            Success = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Success,
            Failure = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Failure
        };
        #endregion
    }
}
```

[image: Script Task Code]

Executing the package will display the variable value in *`MessageBox`*.

[image: Package Execution]

The package will fail in this sample because the path **`C:\temp\File_1.txt`** does not exist.

[image: Package Failure]

#### Response to OP's comment:

> I did what you're showing me here, seems that my problem is that since the User::srcFile variable is added as a ReadWriteVariables to the script task (since i need to do some stuff with it in the same script) it's kinda locked so the User::srcFull variable who's definition is @[User::srcPath] + @[User::srcFile] cannot be evaluated..

I modified the variable *`srcFull`* from *`ReadOnlyVariables`* to **`ReadWriteVariables`** on *Script Task Editor* and the expression still evaluated correctly. I created those three files in the sample input and the package displayed each path correctly in the message box and completed the execution successfully.

Adding the variables *`srcPath`* and *`srcFile`* to the **`ReadWriteVariables`** section of Script Task Editor will only result in a conflict because now both *Script Task* and *Foreach Loop Container* are trying to update the same variables.

Comment: I did what you're showing me here, seems that my problem is that since the `User::srcFile` variable is added as a `ReadWriteVariables` to the script task (since i need to do some stuff with it in the same script) it's kinda locked so the `User::srcFull` variable who's definition is `@[User::srcPath] +  @[User::srcFile]`  cannot be evaluated...

Comment: try to add the `srcFile` and the `srcPath` as a `ReadWriteVariables` to the script task, and let me know if your script still works...

Comment: i made a different script just for this task and it seems to work.

Answer (score 1):

For starters, I would raise information events with all three variables prior to the call to `File.Exists`:

```
public void chkIfExist()
{
    bool fireAgain = true;
    Dts.Events.FireInformation(0,
        "MyScriptTask",
        String.Format("srcPath is \"{0}\"", Dts.Variables["User::srcPath"].Value),
        "",
        0,
        ref fireAgain);
    Dts.Events.FireInformation(0,
        "MyScriptTask",
        String.Format("srcFile is \"{0}\"", Dts.Variables["User::srcFile"].Value),
        "",
        0,
        ref fireAgain);
    Dts.Events.FireInformation(0,
        "MyScriptTask",
        String.Format("srcFull is \"{0}\"", Dts.Variables["User::srcFull"].Value),
        "",
        0,
        ref fireAgain);
    string fullPath = Dts.Variables["User::srcFull"].Value.ToString();
    if (System.IO.File.Exists(fullPath))
    {
        Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
    }
    else
    {
        Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Failure;
    }
}
```

The purpose here is to get a better view of what the failing record looks like.

Answer (score -1):

You need to pass all the variables in the `ReadOnlyVariables` section in order for the scriptTask to evaluate them. In your case, I think your ReadOnlyVariables should be `srcPath, srcFile, srcFull`